# How to handle the html and css of one side image and other side content and vice versa

Tags: html, css

I am working on project and in my design there is one row and in first col there is image and in second col there is content.in next row there is the content first and then a col for image.I also attched its design image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i3Mf.jpg)  how to handle it.I tried the bootstrap pull push cols but i am confused can i use this ,if i use this then how it will cover in responsive.

```
 <div class="hundred-percent-width">
                                <div class="ad-col-row ad-odd-row ad-margin-bottom-50">
                                    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
                                       <div class="feature-box-thumb border-right">
                                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/shop-v2-1.jpg" alt="feature-block" width="1047" height="596" /></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                                        <div class="ad-pad-sq">
                                            <div class="ad-sec-title ad-uline-left ad-margin-bottom-20">
                                                <h4>VEHICLE NAME J33D3</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--ad-sec-title closed-->
                                            <div class="ad-sec-content ad-margin-bottom-20">
                                                <span class="bold-heading">features</span>
                                                <ul class="regular-text ad-margin-left-30">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>Model: JVC-2255L</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>Brand: JVC Inc.</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>  Capecity : 200tn</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>   Power: 3000Hp</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span> Engine: v8</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>  Average: 2kmpl</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span> Services: world wide</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--ad-sec-content-->
                                            <div class="ad-sec-content ad-margin-bottom-20">
                                                <span class="bold-heading">Description:</span>
                                                <p>We will assign a project manager, field superintendent, engineer and other staff members as required to effectively manage the construction process.</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--ad-sec-content-->
                                            <div class="">
                                                <div class="ad-left-float ad-margin-right">
                                                    <a class="button ad-download-link btn-small" href="#/"><i class="fa fa-download button__icon"></i><span><i style="margin-right:20px;" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>DOWNLOAD Full  brochure</span></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--ad-grey-bdr lcosed-->
                                                <div class="ad-left-float btn-xs">
                                                    <a href="#/" class="button button-by-default btn-small">GET A QUOTE</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--ad-red-btn closed-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--vehicle-content closed-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--ad-col-row-closed-->
                            </div>
                            <!--hundred-percent-width closed-->
                            <div class="hundred-percent-width">
                                <div class="ad-col-row ad-even-row ad-margin-bottom-50">
                                    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 interchange-first">
                                       <div class="feature-box-thumb border-left"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/shop-v2-2.jpg" alt="feature-block" width="1047" height="596" /></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 interchange-second">
                                        <div class="ad-pad-sq">
                                            <div class="ad-sec-title ad-uline-left ad-margin-bottom-20">
                                                <h4>VEHICLE NAME J33D3</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--ad-sec-title closed-->
                                            <div class="ad-sec-content ad-margin-bottom-20">
                                                <span class="bold-heading">features</span>
                                                <ul class="regular-text ad-margin-left-30">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>Model: JVC-2255L</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>Brand: JVC Inc.</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>  Capecity : 200tn</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>   Power: 3000Hp</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span> Engine: v8</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>  Average: 2kmpl</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span> Services: world wide</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--ad-sec-content-->
                                            <div class="ad-sec-content ad-margin-bottom-20">
                                                <span class="bold-heading">Description:</span>
                                                <p>We will assign a project manager, field superintendent, engineer and other staff members as required to effectively manage the construction process.</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--ad-sec-content-->
                                            <div class="">
                                                <div class="ad-left-float ad-margin-right">
                                                    <a class="button ad-download-link btn-small" href="#/"><i class="fa fa-download button__icon"></i><span><i style="margin-right:20px;" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>DOWNLOAD Full  brochure</span></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--ad-grey-bdr lcosed-->
                                                <div class="ad-left-float btn-xs">
                                                    <a href="#/" class="button button-by-default btn-small">GET A QUOTE</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--ad-red-btn closed-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--vehicle-content closed-->
                                    </div>
                                    <!--vehicle-content closed-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--hundred-percent-width closed-->

                            <div class="hundred-percent-width">
                                <div class="ad-col-row ad-odd-row ad-margin-bottom-50">
                                    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
                                        <div class="feature-box-thumb border-right"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/shop-v2-1.jpg" alt="feature-block" width="1047" height="596" /></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                                        <div class="ad-pad-sq">
                                            <div class="ad-sec-title ad-uline-left ad-margin-bottom-20">
                                                <h4>VEHICLE NAME J33D3</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--ad-sec-title closed-->
                                            <div class="ad-sec-content ad-margin-bottom-20">
                                                <span class="bold-heading">features</span>
                                                <ul class="regular-text ad-margin-left-30">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>Model: JVC-2255L</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>Brand: JVC Inc.</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>  Capecity : 200tn</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>   Power: 3000Hp</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span> Engine: v8</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span>  Average: 2kmpl</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span> Services: world wide</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--ad-sec-content-->
                                            <div class="ad-sec-content ad-margin-bottom-20">
                                                <span class="bold-heading">Description:</span>
                                                <p>We will assign a project manager, field superintendent, engineer and other staff members as required to effectively manage the construction process.</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--ad-sec-content-->
                                            <div class="">
                                                <div class="ad-left-float ad-margin-right">
                                                    <a class="button ad-download-link btn-small" href="#/"><i class="fa fa-download button__icon"></i><span><i style="margin-right:20px;" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>DOWNLOAD Full  brochure</span></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--ad-grey-bdr lcosed-->
                                                <div class="ad-left-float btn-xs">
                                                    <a href="#/" class="button button-by-default btn-small">GET A QUOTE</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--ad-red-btn closed-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--vehicle-content closed-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--ad-col-row-closed-->
                            </div>
                            <!--hundred-percent-width closed--
```

Comment: Also question is little bit confused. Describe (with pictures inside your post, not links) what you want to achieve, possibly code you already have (using code snippets) and why it doesn't work as expected...

Comment: Are you generating content or is it static?

Comment: Attach some code example. [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @Justinas am creating dynamic content

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti  how can handle the html with css of even, odd row.In odd row there is a image in first col and then content in second col.In even row there is content in first col and image in second col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with a lot of assumptions here, but since you said the content is dynamic, hope this helps:

```
 <?php
 //Assuming you have a table ( let's call it "posts") with at least the following 3 fields : id , img_name , content
 //Assuming you have some sort of DB connector  ( I'll call it $dbc )
 //This is just a general example, adapt it to your own mysql and php

 $q = 'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by id';
 $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
 $i = 0;

 if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0){
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){

 if ($i % 2 == 0) { ?>

   <div style="width: 60%; float: left;" > <img src="path_on_your_host/<?php echo $row['img_name']; ?>" ></div>
   <div style="width: 30%; position: relative"> <p> <?php echo $row['content']; ?></p></div>
   <?php
} else { ?>

   <div style="width: 30%; float: left;"> <p> <?php echo $row['content']; ?></p></div>
   <div style="width: 60%; position: relative" > <img src="path_on_your_host/<?php echo $row['img_name']; ?>" ></div>
  <?
}

$i++;
}
}

?>
```

Didn't tested the code..possible to contain some errors, but the idea is OK.